# Using chrome not signed in and then sign-in/sign-out. What happens

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, gmail, bookmarks, google-accounts

If I am using chrome in a PC and I am not signed in and have bookmarks and saved passwords etc
if I sign-in with my gmail account and then sign-out does this mess up the existing bookmarks and saved passwords, cookies etc?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see what happens?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Because I want to avoid messing things up

Comment: So test it with a single bookmark and a single password which you save somewhere else first.

Comment: @DavidPostill: How am I supposed to do that? With another PC?

Comment: Jim, you can open another profile in Chrome and run this test. It is trivial AND nondestructive.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it depends.

The worst case requires that nobody
had ever signed into Chrome on that Chrome profile,
and that you then sign into Chrome on the same Chrome profile.
You would then be asked whether to merge everything from your https://chrome.google.com/sync with what's already on the profile, or replace the local data them with your synced data.
That is if you chose to even sync anything when signing into Chrome.

Mitigating factors :

- Using the same Chrome profile, you don't sign in to Chrome but only sign into Google https://accounts.google.com/accountchooser
- On the same profile, if somebody[1] had previously signed into Chrome (even if they had signed out but chosen not to remove local data), and you then attempted to sign into Chrome
  using your account, it would prompt you to create a new Chrome profile - which you should've done in the first place, regardless of how the existing profile was setup.

[1] different account that you were using to sign in.